# AS3 code that automatically updates the player's score

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a game in which the character runs in place and the background moves from left to right. However I cant think of the code which will set the score to how much the person has run. Hope you guys are following. It is something similar to the mobile application "Subway Surf". Basically, the score is the distance the person has run and has to be functioning as soon as the game is initiated. Hopefully you guys can help.

P.S. Not really a pro with AS3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's a poorly-worded question, so here's an answer to match: use a Timer and add score as a function of time. If you can ask a better question, explaining, for instance, how or if the runner's speed varies, you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Okay, scratch that, I'll rephrase the question. What I was asking before was, what would be the code which would calculate the score for an endless running game. Endless running refers to games such as "Temple Run", "Subway Surf".